# Issue when removing row from ComboBox model

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols2

I have an `ComboBox` in my QML file:

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
// ...
ComboBox {
    id: serailPortNameBox
    model: availableSerialPortsModel
    textRole: "display"
}
```

and model `availableSerialPortsModel` that contains serial port names currently available in system:

```
QStringListModel availableSerialPortsModel;
QList<QSerialPortInfo> portsList = QSerialPortInfo::availablePorts();
for (auto port : portsList) {
    int row = availableSerialPortsModel.rowCount();
    availableSerialPortsModel.insertRow(row);
    QModelIndex index = availableSerialPortsModel.index(row);
    availableSerialPortsModel.setData(index, port.portName(), Qt::DisplayRole);
}
// ...
engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("availableSerialPortsModel", availableSerialPortsModel);
```

[image: combobox before removing]

When I'm removing some serial port:

```
for (int row = availableSerialPortsModel.rowCount() - 1; row >= 0; --row) {
    QModelIndex index = availableSerialPortsModel.index(row);
    QString name = availableSerialPortsModel.data(index, Qt::DisplayRole).toString();

    if (portsToRemove.contains(name)) {
        availableSerialPortsModel.removeRow(row);
    }
}
```

`ComboBox` removes this port with some visual issue:
[image: combobox after removing]

Is it just a bug og `ComboBox` or am I doing something wrong? My Qt version is 5.7.0 on a Apple device with Sierra 10.12.2.

[Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0By2N30gBjyToUmtvb2w2YndSOUE/view?usp=sharing) a simple project that reproduces the issue.

Comment: You need to inform the world that you are removing rows. See http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#beginRemoveRows and http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#endRemoveRows

Comment: This was a bug in Qt 5.7.0, which was fixed in Qt 5.7.1: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-54573 - try upgrading.

Comment: @Jesper Juhl QStringListModel is complete class, `removeRow()` realization already call this functions.

Comment: @jpnurmi, thank you, upgrading solve the problem.

Comment: Do not change to "SOLVED". Just post the bugreport problem as an answer and state that upgrading to 5.7.1 solved the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is Qt 5.7.0 bug ([bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-54573](http://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-54573)). Upgrading to Qt 5.7.1 id solved the problem.